# How can I install USB-N13 on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, linux-mint, firmware

How do you install the Asus USB-N13 wireless adapter, 802.11b/g/n model onto mint 11 64bit CD version. The driver/firmware is not included by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the bin file, [this might be it, but I can't test anymore](http://code.deeproot.in/deepofix/export/693/trunk/var/rootfs/lib/firmware/rt3071.bin), you can then use `sudo nautilus` to move it into the firmware folder, then reboot.

**Warning:** The driver causes your OS to ***hang occasionally*** and does not work properly. I advise you to get a new wireless adapter. I guess that's why the driver wasn't included out of the box...

Comment: Can you provide a link to said file?

Comment: I cant remember exactly what the name was, because I installed a new operating system over the old one, but it was like rt3070.bin, or something.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is a driver [available directly](http://ca.asus.com/en/Networks/Wireless_Adapters/USBN13/#download) from Asus, and is available for Linux. One is just a driver, while the other includes some sort of client.

Just extract the file, then `cd` into the directory. Run `./configure` along with `make` and `make install`

Comment: I distinctly remember the driver from that site not working...

Comment: You likely installed it wrong then.

Comment: Considering the question is "how to install", that makes the answer still wrong.

Comment: @NotaName there, installation instructionsf or you.

Comment: Actually, it was a compile error. Frankly I know the bin worked. so w/e. Better solution is to buy a new adapter either way.

Comment: Also, I'm not going to both with anymore. Goodbye.